# Cartoon about a boy who goes to an underground world and collects monster pets

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There was this cartoon I watched when I was a kid (watched around 2008–2015), and I cannot remember its name. All I can remember about this cartoon is that the main character followed in his dad's footsteps to go to this underground world accompanied by a (I think) monster pet of some sort (pretty sure it could shoot fire). His dad had made him promise to only go after he became a certain age. After that he ends up finding/saving/raising more of these monster pets. As for the people that live down there, I remember a few scenes where they themselves raise these pets for various reasons (especially combat as they can do things like breathe fire and have other magical abilities) and at one point these people form an expedition to try and get to the surface, which they believe is some fantasy place filled with gold and riches. This leads the mc to go and close the small tunnel he came in. I also vaguely remember him forming some sort of team of other like-minded people and creating a base of sorts.

Unfortunately, this is about all I can remember about the cartoon/possibly anime (although I doubt it is). I was thinking it might have only been an arc of some other cartoon but based on the part about him closing the tunnel for good I find that highly unlikely. Additionally, based on the structure of what I can remember, I think it had episodes. Any help would be appreciated as I cannot find a trace of it.

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate. That does not mean it is a bad question, just that it's one that we've had before, and this links it in the system. You will still get points for upvotes on your question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

Gosh, after an hour I remembered that it had 'terra' in its title. After some searching, I finally found it: Slugterra.

Comment: It's great that you figured it out.  Please don't forget to come back and accept your answer so the question is marked as answered.